# What does Victor Wooten refers to in his Justice Song in album "Show of Hands"?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

In the [lyrics](https://genius.com/Victor-wooten-justice-lyrics) of song "Justice" by Victor Wooten in his 1996 Album "Show of Hands" he says:

> Twenty two cops on the scene /
>   And only 4 go to trial

Is there a specific episode he is referring to?

Comment: my best guess is currently that he was referring to Rodney King beating ('91-'92), where 4 went to trial (could not find references on exactly 22 being on the scene). will leave it open if someone founds more corroboration (or an alternative).